# class_exists returns true if file has same name but class does not have same name

Tags: php

There is a php `file` named `RefGererCauseRiskView.php` ; inside this file there is the declaration and definition of a `class` :

```
<?php
class C_RefGererCauseRiskView extends View {
   ...
}
?>
```

At runtime the following statement returns true : `if (class_exists('RefGererCauseRiskView'))`

So what is wrong ?

**EDIT :**

framework mvc :

index.php :

```
<?php

$action_factory =& new ActionFactory() ;
$action_factory->getAction(true) ;
$action_factory->execute() ;

?>
```

ActionFactory :

```
<?php

class Action {
    function Action() {}
    function execute() {}
}

class ActionResult {
    var $mapping;
    var $data;

    function ActionResult($mapping, $data) {
        $this->mapping = $mapping;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    function getViewMapping() {return $this->mapping;}
    function getResultData() {return $this->data;}
}

class View {
    function View() {}
    function processView($data) {}
}

class ActionFactory {

    var $action_class = null ;

    function ActionFactory () {}

    function getAction() {

        define('ACTION', isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'Main');

        $relative_path = trim(relative_path());

        $dir_actions = "";
        if ($relative_path != "index.php" && $relative_path != "mp.php") {
            $tab_action = explode(".", $relative_path);
            $dir_actions = $tab_action[0]."/";
        }
        $action_class = ACTION.'Action' ;

        if ( !class_exists($action_class, false) ) {
            $file_actions = RP_ACTIONS.$dir_actions.$action_class.'.php';
            if ( file_exists($file_actions)) {
                require_once $file_actions ;
            } else {
                die($file_actions . " !");
            }
        }
        $this->action_class =& new $action_class() ;
    }

    function execute() {
        $action_result = $this->action_class->execute();
        $view_factory =& new ViewFactory() ;
        $view = $view_factory->getView() ;
        $view->processView($action_result);
    }

}

class ViewFactory {

    function ViewFactory() {}

    function getView() {

        $view_class   = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])?$_REQUEST['action']:'Main').'View' ;

        $relative_path = relative_path();

        $dir_views = "";
        if ($relative_path != "index.php" && $relative_path != "mp.php") {
            $tab_action = explode(".", $relative_path);
            $dir_views = $tab_action[0]."/";
        }
        $action_class = ACTION.'View' ;

        if ( !class_exists($view_class, false) ) {
            $file_views = RP_VIEWS.$dir_views.$action_class.'.php';
            if ( file_exists($file_views)) {
                require_once $file_views ;
            } else {
                die($file_views . " !");
            }
        }
        return new $view_class();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal piece of code which demonstrates this?  I tried this: <?phpclass View {
}
class C_RefGererCauseRiskView extends View {
}
if (class_exists('RefGererCauseRiskView')) echo "Its there!\n";
else echo "Not there!\n";
and it says "Not there" (with file named as you say...  Also please post your platform, PHP version and any autoloaders you are using.

Comment: I use wampserver 2.5 , I dont know what autoloaders are used ; see my edited post for the framework I m using.

Comment: in fact the parameter value of the function class_exists comes dynamically from the menu clicked.

Comment: So what's failing - the class_exists($view_class...?  When you log $view_class, what is it?  Try print_r(get_declared_classes()) and see if the class is declared.  I'm not a wamp expert, but I think its just a php5.5 server in 2.5, and pretty sure if the class_exists, its been declared somewhere.  Lastly, if it is declared, try dumping class_parents("RefGererCauseRiskView", false) to at least see it's lineage...